# Java - Sockets transfer byte[] to .wav

Tags: java, json, sockets, audio, file-io

I'm making a socket based connection between a server and a client, the client sends a byte[], obtain by the AudioInputStream, within a JSON, the server receives the JSON process it another JSON with other information, but the byte[] remains the same, but when I try to stream it back to .wav I get this:

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1121)
at sweepvoiceclient.SendMessage.jButton2ActionPerformed(SendMessage.java:162)
at sweepvoiceclient.SendMessage.access$000(SendMessage.java:26)
at sweepvoiceclient.SendMessage$1.actionPerformed(SendMessage.java:74)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The code for my client is:

```
 try {

        File file = new File("audio.wav");

        AudioInputStream inputStream = 
                AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

        byte [] fileContent = new byte [(int)file.length()];


        inputStream.read(fileContent);


        JsonObject objectToSend = new Message(
            Integer.parseInt(senderField.getText()),
            Integer.parseInt(receiverField.getText()),
            fileContent
        ).createJson();

    System.out.println(objectToSend.toString());

    SweepVoiceClientSocket socket = new  SweepVoiceClientSocket();

    socket.write(objectToSend);

    JsonObject object = socket.read();

    AudioInputStream source = AudioSystem
            .getAudioInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(
                            Base64.decode(object.getString("message"))
                        )
                    )
            );

    AudioInputStream pcm = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, source);
    AudioSystem.write( 
            pcm,
            AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, 
            new File("nvo.wav"));

    } catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
```

And the server the only thing that does is Base64.decode and Base64.encode.

Is that the right way to do it???
Is there another way more effective???
Which???

THANK YOU

Comment: AudioInputStream do decode and translate. The result length won't be `file.length`

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with:

```
  inputStream.read(fileContent);

  // or your previous version
  while (inputStream.read(fileContent) != -1){}
```

You should check how many bytes was readed, and in the next while execution start to save readed byte to proper offset in array.

```
    byte [] fileContent = new byte [size];

    int readed=0;
    while (readed<size) {
        int r = inputStream.read(fileContent, readed, size-readed);
        if (r<0) break;
        readed = readed + r;
    }
```

Comment: That was something I tried, but it gave my the same result as showed now.

Comment: But for sure it is a big problem